# How to prevent space key function on mobile phones via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I am debugging on chrome console space keyCode is 32 and I can prevent space action work fine but on android phones I can not manage to prevent space action.How Can I handle it?

I tried to handle that on ('click touchstart'), keydown and `e.keyCode==229` but Fail.

```
 $("#registerForm [name='Email']").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you tried running this https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html on Android to check the returned Keycode ? Otherwise there are also plenty cool libs like keyboard.js that abstract that matter for you :)

Comment: From [this page](https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices.html#hid-keyboard-and-keypad-page-0x07) I understand that spacebar on Android has the keyCode 63 (0x003e)

Comment: @DaniloKörber I'm sorry but its not.

Comment: @guillaumepotier I tried on phone but it returns 229 for all buttons.